# Custom Fonts CSS - Error

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Well I have been attempting to add custom fonts on my page which are not a font you would find on ever computer. I tryed implementing this by following [this](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) but it just seems to default to Agency FB. Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face  {
  font-family: "911";
  src: url('fonts/911v2.eot'); /* here you go, IE */
}

@font-face  {
  font-family: "911";
  src: url(//:) format ('no404'), url('fonts/911v2.ttf') format('truetype'); /* tricky! */
}

p.myFont {
    font-family: "911", "Agency FB", verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-size: large;
    color: black;
}
```

I used a converter to convert the font from ttf to eot. And here is the relevent HTML:

```
<p class="myFont">Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary</p>
```

Any ideas?

Note that the fonts folder is in the root of the webpage (where the index page is located)

**Edit:**

[image] in the fonts folder -> [image]

**Edit 2:**

Still does not work, but here is what I have got at the moment:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '911';
  src: url('/fonts/911v2.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/911v2.ttf') format('truetype');
}

p.myFont {
    font-family: '911', "Agency FB", verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-size: large;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: are your paths correct? I mean, `..fonts/` or `fonts/`?

Comment: Do you have both the `.ttf` and the `.eot` in the folder?

Comment: @elclanrs I posted a screenshot of the folder hierarchy.

Comment: 911v2 doesn't have an extension... It means that your `911v2.ttf` is missing when referencing in the url. Either use the `.eot` file or add the `.ttf` file in the folder.

Comment: @e-bachoNo, it does have an extension (ttf), it is just not show because it is a "known" file extension.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the URL is relative. Did you try to use `911v2.ttf` rather than `fonts/911v2.ttf` for the URL? Also did you try referencing the `.eot` instead of the `.ttf`?

Comment: @e-bacho yup tryed that, and one other thing (I may seem obiovious) is that if I remove the "fallbacks" for the fonts, and just leave 911, it defaults to times.

Answer (score 1):

I use font packs from [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com).  This is what the css looks like in order to work in the widest set of browsers:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "OpenSansLight";
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot");
    src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h2 {
  font: 16pt "OpenSansLight", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I'm currently using this in a few of my sites and it works great!

Comment: My upvote for fontsquirell, a great starting point for every time one needs custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The final bit of that article suggests a declaration more like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '911';
  src: url('/fonts/911v2.eot?') format('eot'), url('/fonts/911v2.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

...or:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '911';
  src: url('/fonts/911v2.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/911v2.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

...of course, if you can live with the IE 404:

```
/*IE*/
@font-face { 
font-family: '911'; 
src: url('/fonts/911v2.eot'); 
}

/*CSS3*/
@font-face { 
font-family: '911'; 
src: url('/fonts/911v2.ttf') format(truetype); 
}
```

Comment: well - I'm not sure what's up, but I went ahead and included the basic way of integrating.  You may also want to make sure the font you're using can support the font-size it would be targeting.  I'm not sure what size 'large' actually is.

Comment: Yup, it supports it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp I tryed it with and without it with little difference but the font size.

Comment: any chance you can setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, I would prefer straight CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#HomePlace%3ahome) a bunch lately and have had much better results using the links in the head of my html instead of using the importing directly to my style sheet.

Basically that is a separate style sheet with this in it:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Dosis';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Dosis Regular'), local('Dosis-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/dosis/v1/Ewe0SEXPrakEimFzbOGwB6CWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.woff') format('woff');
}
```

And the link referencing it in the head is:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Also, you might want to thin of using '911' instead of "911" in the font-family and font-face.